# How to build a id checker

Tags: php, android, mysql

After trying my self I'm kinda failing, I basically need to build an PHP + SQL system where all i pass is an ID into it and see if that id's license has expired.

if it hasn't expired then rewrite its license down by 1.
(license should starts at 20)

So basically:
(After connected from an android device passing a String ID)

1. connect to the database
2. connect to the table ( table has ID and License fields)
3. check if the ID is within the database
4. If the id  is within the database then
5. check its license

   - if its license is = 0, then stop everything and return back with "false"
   - if the license is > 0, then license-1 and return back "true"
6. if the ID is not within the database
7. then insert the ID into the table with license value at `20` and return `true`

Comment: Hard to understand the question, put some code or sudo code to help understand what u are trying to achieve.

Comment: i have an application (android) that needs to check its licence on running. So i want a database of users who run my application, and check to see if theyre licence is valid

Comment: @tsegay I had not understood that by "sudo" code you meant PSEUDO code as Galen's :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the standard mysql function calls in a long time, so bear with me.

```
//Connect stuff has been done...
$query = "SELECT ID, license
          FROM table
          WHERE ID = '$someID'";
$result = query($query);
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
  $row = $result->fetch();
  if($row['license'] == 0)
    return false;
  else{
    $license = $row['license'] - 1;
    $query = "UPDATE table SET license = '$license' WHERE ID = '$someID'";
    query($query);
    return true;
  }
}
else{
   $query = "INSERT INTO table(ID, license) VALUES('$someID', 20)";
   query($query);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: this has sql injection written all over it

Comment: Yes, but I was just trying to convey the concept.

Comment: He's talking about using the php variables in the sql statements. You have to escape the values correctly or people can do nasty things to your databases. Would ID be entered by the user? If so, you can't just use it in a query right away.

Comment: no this whole process will have no interaction done by the user, everything is done automatically via progrimatically

Comment: @jaime: you put actual code in. i wanted to make sure he didnt copy and paste this.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code

```
query = select license from table where id=:id
if count(query) {
    if (license <= 0) {
        return false
    }
    license--;
    update table set license=:license where id=:id
    return true
}
else {
    insert into table(id, license) values(:id, 20)
    return true
}
```